# Color syntax in less files

Tags: css, visual-studio, less

I use Visual Studio 2012 to create ASP.NET Webpages. To improve my sheet styles I started use LESS library.
My question is: it's possible to color syntax in files with less extension in the same way like css file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is possible with plugin [Mindscape Web Workbench](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2b96d16a-c986-4501-8f97-8008f9db141a).

More info in: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CoffeeScriptSassAndLESSSupportForVisualStudioAndASPNETWithTheMindscapeWebWorkbench.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Now there is also [Web Essentials 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6), which looks similar to Mindscape Web Workbench. Have only tried Web Essentials which is great, so cannot recommend one over the other.